# Replace StringBuffer/StringBuilder by String

Tags: java, string, netbeans, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

Why does NetBeans suggest that I replace `StringBuffer` / `StringBuilder` by `String`?

It shows me a warning message when I write:

```
StringBuilder demo = new StringBuilder("Hello");
```

Comment: Can you share some more code -- are you actually appending anything to `demo`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic, If I use any StringBuffer/StringBuilder specific methods, the warning goes away. I was just curious why it suggest that before I do anything with *demo*.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of writing

```
StringBuilder demo = new StringBuilder("Hello");
```

this is simpler and you don't have to allocate a StringBuilder for it:

```
String demo = "Hello";
```

If you use a method which means it has to be a StringBuilder, the warning should go away.

e.g.

```
StringBuilder demo = new StringBuilder("Hello");
demo.append(" World ");
demo.append(128);
```

Answer (score 3):

> Replace StringBuffer/StringBuilder by String
>
> The hint will find and
> offer to replace instances of StringBuffer or StringBuilder which are
> accessed using ordinary String methods and are never passed out of the
> method, or assigned to another variable. Keeping such data in
> StringBuffer/Builder is pointless, and String would be more efficient.

From netbeans [wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_Hints).